# Matching a path with values from an array in Neo4j

Tags: neo4j

Given that I have the node type `Component` and the relationship `HAS_CHILD_COMPONENT`, with a repeting relationship like the following example:

`(a:Component {value: 'a'})-[:HAS_CHILD_COMPONENT]->(b:Component {value: 'b'})-[:HAS_CHILD_COMPONENT]->(c:Component {value: 'c'})`

I would like to query and return the `(:Component {value: 'c'})` node in a way where I specify the full path.
It could be written litteraly like above but, in my use-case I'd also like to be able to query for a potential node `(:Component {value: 'd'})` - three relationships away from `(:Component {value: 'a'})`.

Is there a way to write a query by supplying it an array with the matching values along the path?

If the query intended to find `(:Component {value: 'c'})`, the query would be supplied with the array parameter:

`['a', 'b', 'c']`.

To find the node `(:Component) {value: 'd'})` the supplied array would be:

`['a', 'b', 'c', 'd']`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does something like this get you going? Supply an array of values to the query, use the beginning and end values in the supplied array to anchor the path and then use `reduce` to ensure the path contains the commponents supplied in the array.

```
WITH ['a','b','c','d'] AS components
MATCH path=(start:Component)-[:HAS_CHILD_COMPONENT*..4]->(end:Component)
WHERE start.value = components[0] 
AND end.value = components[size(components)-1]
AND reduce(values = [], n in nodes(path) | values + [n.value])
RETURN path
```

Comment: Yeah, I had a feeling it was something along those lines.
Thanks for the help :)
This exact query ended up working for me:

`WITH 
  ['a','b','c','d'] AS components
MATCH 
  path=(start:Component)-[:HAS_CHILD_COMPONENT*1..]->(end:Component)
WHERE 
  start.value = components[0] AND 
  end.value = components[size(components)-1]
WITH 
  end,  
  reduce(values = [], n in nodes(path) | values + [n.value]) as reducedValues
WHERE 
  reducedValues = components
RETURN end`